# Sobolev space compact embeddings

Tags: sobolev-spaces

Just a quick question.  Under what conditions does $L^2(\Omega)$ embed compactly into the dual Sobolev space $H^{-1}(\Omega)$?  Specifically, I'm looking for conditions on a bounded domain $\Omega\subset \mathbb{C}^n$.  Any good references?

Comment: It's the adjoint of the embedding of $H^1_0(\Omega)$ into $L^2(\Omega)$, and an operator is compact iff its adjoint is.  So this should follow from the usual Sobolev embedding theorems.

Comment: This is "Schauder's theorem", right?

Comment: @Neal Yes it is.

Answer (score 6):

For the sake of completeness, taking Nate Eldredge's comment and elevating to an answer. This is known as Schauder's theorem; the statement (as Nate Eldredge says) is that an operator is compact iff its adjoint is compact. A proof sketch can be found in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/41432/easy-proof-adjointcompact-compact) MSE answer. In this context, $L^2(\Omega)$ will embed compactly into $H^{-1}(\Omega)$ exactly when $H^1_0(\Omega)$ embeds compactly into $L^2(\Omega)$, which is the case when $\Omega$ is bounded by the Rellich-Kondrachov theorem.